# IntelliJ IDEA: Need help to set shortcut line

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

I am new to coding ... and i am using IntelliJ idea ... my question is ...

i want to make some shortcut for lines... like ...

```
System.out.println(); or 
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); ..
```

and if i type like *sop* it will print ..**system.out.println();** ... as those type of lines i have to use almost every code ... so it will be good if i can make shortcuts for those. is it possible to make this kinda shortcut in Intellij???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Live Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html) and there are a couple of them predefined. You can easily define your own.

The first one for `System.out.println()` is used by printing `sout` and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

A couple of the predefined ones can be found in `Help` -> `Default Keymap Reference`:

[image]

As you can see pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> will bring up a list of available [Live Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html).